How to concat a specific column with the comma in emacs org table?
I have a table as follows, how do I get the last convert row?
The row is concat the column items from @2..@6.
Thanks for your help.
simple example
| A       |         1 |
|---------+-----------|
| Rep     |         4 |
| Rep     |         5 |
| Rep     |         5 |
| Rep     |         2 |
| Rep     |         6 |
|---------+-----------|
| convert | 4,5,5,2,6 |

complex example
| A       |         1 |         3 |
|---------+-----------+-----------|
| Rep     |         4 |         7 |
| Rep     |         5 |         2 |
| Rep     |         5 |         8 |
| Rep     |         2 |         9 |
| Rep     |         6 |         9 |
|---------+-----------+-----------|
| convert | 4,5,5,2,6 | 7,2,8,9,9 |


